# Problems with the representation in the workspace of the numbers in fixed point

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-deployment, fixed-point

Hi everyone and thanks in advance!

I am having problems with the function fi (Matlab function to convert data in fixed point type). I am using Matlab R2015a.
**When I use this function with a vector the representation in the workspace is not correct from the 65 component.**

The representation works in loop, repeating the same data each 64 component so the representation in the workspace is only correct in the first 64 components of the vector. Nevertheless the data in each component in the vector is correct, if I print the info or copy and paste the value, it is different (and correct) from the representation in the workspace. Here is some code that I have used:

```
clear all;close all;

rawWidth=16;
rawFracLen=0;
rawIsSigned       = false;
rawBinType        = numerictype('WordLength',rawWidth,'FractionLength',rawFracLen);
rawBinType.Signed = rawIsSigned;
N=10000;
x=rand(1,1000)*N;
A=fi(x,'numerictype',rawBinType);
```

**Does Anyone know how to fix this problem or why is this produced?** I am having problems with the debugging of a script that uses this function many times with different vectors.

[image with the wrong representation of the data in the workspace and the real data printed in the command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWzaj.png)

Comment: I had the same problem and I didn't find a solution

Comment: That is really crazy behavior indeed. Consider contacting Mathworks for explanation. I can definetly reproduce it